# ".exe file has stopped working" when file isn't in solution folder - ScreenReaderAPIWrapper causing the crash

Tags: visual-studio, exe, screen-readers

Running the solution without problems in Visual studio 2017, or directly through .exe file in solution folder (inside release and debug folders). But when the ".exe" file is not in the solution folder, it will crash and stop working.

I found that these lines are causing the issue:

```
ScreenReaderAPIWrapper.ScreenReader sc = new ScreenReaderAPIWrapper.ScreenReader();
sc.SayString(textDisplay.Text.ToString());
```

Comment: What API library do you use?

Comment: I'm using ScreenReaderAPIWrapper library.

Comment: aha. It seems, it's a wrapper around QuentinC's library, so you should have the corresponding DLLs like jfwapi.dll, NvdaController32.dll and so on. Try to move them along with your executable. If that helps, I'll elaborate it as an answer.

Comment: Yes, that helps. I moved ScreenReaderAPIWrapper.dll, nvdaControllerClient.dll and ScreenReaderAPI.dll along with my executable. How can i solve it without moving dll files?

Comment: There is no way, sorry, you have to provide the DLLs for this to work. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `ScreenReaderAPIWrapper` library for .net you're using is a wrapper around another library called [UniversalSpeech](https://github.com/qtnc/UniversalSpeech). There are several solutions alike out there, like Davy Kager's Tolk or Chris Toth's AccessibleOutput. All of these libraries make use of native APIs provided by corresponding screen reader modules (`jfwapi.dll`, `saapi32.dll`, `NvdaController32.dll` and others).
For these libraries to work, you have to provide all of the needed DLLs along with your executable, otherwise you'll get those errors about the exe file that stopped working.
If you need to distribute your program, consider using installer tools like [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) or [InnoSetup](http://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to pack all needed files into one single installer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll definitely consider using those tools.